# How to catch all links that are in Windows clipboard?

Tags: java, windows, href, clipboard

I would realize a method for catch all links that are in Windows clipboard when i select and copy a text HTML, but i do not found any example to realize it. 
I'm already know how to catch string from clipboard but when try to print it (or paste it), i lost formatting (and relative href).
Any idea?

Comment: You can retrieve the clipboard data as [DataFlavor.fragmentHtmlFlavor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.html#fragmentHtmlFlavor), then parse it for `<a>` elements, but I know of no clipboard format that includes the document base of the source HTML or any other way to resolve a relative URL in an href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

@VGR: I found your answer very helpful. I use it and i have create this class that copy all HTML data. Now i make/search a parser method to catch links and problem is solved.

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Clipboard clipboard=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        DataFlavor df=DataFlavor.allHtmlFlavor;
        try
        {
            System.out.println("HTML of selected text="+clipboard.getData(df));
        }
        catch(UnsupportedFlavorException|IOException exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```